# Query over three tables

Tags: jquery, sql, database, postgresql

I have the following schema:

```
|partner|
---------
id

|contract|
----------
id    
partner_id
termination_date

|comtract_items|
---------------
id
contract_id 
product_id
```

I want to select all partners which have a valid contract (`termination_date is NULL`) and
with no contracts with the `product_id`'s 392 and 393.

Here is my Query so far:

```
SELECT 
    c.id,
    c.subject
FROM 
    contract_contract c

WHERE
    c.termination_date is NULL or c.termination_date > '2014-12-11'
    and c.id NOT IN (SELECT contract_id
                     FROM contract_item
                     WHERE product_id IN (392, 393))
```

Any ideas how to build the query?

Comment: Your query looks reasonable.  What is the problem?

Comment: You have `contract_contract.subject` in your query, but not in your table layout. Please clarify. Also, the restriction `no contracts with the product_id's 392 and 393` is supposed to rule out the partner of just the contract it applies to.

Comment: its the following relation> one partner can have many contracts and one contract can have many lines. with my query i want get all partner which havnt one of these products in any contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now clear that `"and with no contracts with the product_id's 392 and 393"` is supposed to rule out partners that have ***any*** contract with any of those blacklisted `product_id`s:

```
SELECT *  -- unclear which columns you want
FROM   partner p
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   contract_contract c
   WHERE (c.termination_date IS NULL OR c.termination_date > '2014-12-11')
   AND    c.partner_id = p.id
   )
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   contract_contract c
   JOIN   contract_item ci ON ci.contract_id = c.id
   WHERE  c.partner_id = p.id
   AND    ci.product_id IN (392, 393)
   );
```

In your original query you would probably need **parentheses** to make `OR` bind before `AND`. With standard **[operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE)** `AND` would bind first - probably not what you want there.

However, in the updated query the necessity is gone, because the additional predicate moved to a separate `EXISTS` expression.

Comment: its the following relation> one partner can have many contracts and one contract can have many lines. with my query i want get all partner which havnt one of these products in any contract

Comment: @GeorgSattler: Adapted the query accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were very close, but forgot some parentheses:

```
WHERE (c.termination_date is NULL or c.termination_date > '2014-12-11') and ...
```

Here's how I would do this::

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.partner_id
FROM Contract c
WHERE (c.TerminationDate IS NOT NULL OR c.TerminationDate > CURRENT_DATE)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ContractItem
                WHERE contract_id = c.id
                AND product_id IN (392, 393))
```

Comment: its the following relation> one partner can have many contracts and one contract can have many lines. with my query i want get all partner which havnt one of these products in any contract

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all partner which have a valid contract (termination_date is NULL) and which no contracts with the product id's 392 and 393.

This SQL statement should achieve that

```
SELECT c.partner_id
FROM contract c
INNER JOIN contract_items ci on ci.contract_id = c.id
WHERE (c.termination_date is NULL
    or c.termination_date > '2014-12-11') 
AND ci.productID NOT IN (392, 393);
```